# sklearn BallTree changes data passed to metric

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm using a custom metric function with `sklearn.neighbors.BallTree`, but I'm having issues because it seems that `BallTree` changes the data before it passes it to my metric function. Here's an example to show this:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
data = np.random.randint(0, 20, size=(2, 3))
def metric(x, y):
    print('Data passed to metric')
    print(x)
    print(y)
    return 1

print('Original data')
print(data)
BallTree(data, metric=metric)
```

This gives me

```
Original data
[[12 15  0]
 [ 3  3  7]]
Data passed to metric
[7.5 9.  3.5]
[12. 15.  0.]
Data passed to metric
[7.5 9.  3.5]
[3. 3. 7.]
```

What preprocessing does `BallTree` do before passing the data to `metric`? Is there a way to turn this off? It even seems to change the data between calls to `metric`...

(My real use case - I'm using Levenstein distance as my metric and working with strings. However, since I can't pass in strings directly, I convert each character to a predefined token and pass in an array of the tokens. Since the data is modified, I'm no longer able to undo the encoding to get the strings back in my metric function so that I can correctly calculated the Levenstein distance. If you have a better solution for finding nearest neighbors when working with strings instead of numerical data, I'd be glad to hear that too).

Comment: `If you have a better solution for finding nearest neighbors when working with strings instead of numerical data, I'd be glad to hear that too`
Have you considered using word2vec/annoy?

Comment: The strings I'm working with are short protein sequences. There do exist protein embeddings too, but I'm interested right now in working specifically with distances based on the sequence itself. (also, not sure what annoy is). I ended up just "rounding" the tree nodes to the nearest string representation so I could still use Levenstein distance; still determining how well this approximation works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does NOT.

The `BallTree` object is not changing your data.

1. It creates a copy of your data because:

> Note: if X is a C-contiguous array of doubles then data will not be
>   copied. Otherwise, an internal copy will be made.

2. It calculates the distances between your objects and tree node bounds. As you see bellow, you can use the `get_arrays` function to get the internal arrays, and by checking the source code you realize that the boundary is the `[7.5, 9. , 3.5]`, which is the one to which it's comparing your objects.

[Source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/neighbors/binary_tree.pxi#L1152):

```
def get_arrays(self):
        return (self.data_arr, self.idx_array_arr,
                self.node_data_arr, self.node_bounds_arr)
```

And the output:

```
bt.get_arrays()                                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[x]:                                                                                                                                                                                                           
(array([[12., 15.,  0.],                                                                                                                                                                                           
        [ 3.,  3.,  7.]]), array([0, 1]), array([(0, 2, 1, 1.)],                                                                                                                                                   
       dtype=[('idx_start', '<i8'), ('idx_end', '<i8'), ('is_leaf', '<i8'), ('radius', '<f8')]), array([[[7.5, 9. , 3.5]]]))
```

So your metric will be applied to the data and the nodes, not just your data within themselves, and the nodes are not the same as your data. You can try word embeddings which would allow you to calculate distances without having to decode your data. Not sure what you're trying to do, but maybe a tree based model is not the best way to go for your usecase.

Comment: Yeah, I realized a bit after posting this question that it was asking for distances between points besides those in my data; thanks for clarifying that it needs distances to the tree nodes as well.