# My custom distance function with sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor is getting passed unexpected values

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm using a KNeighborsRegressor to predict a continuous variable with distances calculated from boolean vectors. Everything works if I set the metric to 'jaccard', but I want to see if the Matthews correlation coefficient can increase the accuracy of the prediction. I wrote a simple function that calls sklearn.metrics.matthews_corrcoef and transforms it into a distance from 0 to 1:

```
from sklearn.metrics import matthews_corrcoef
def mcc(x, y):
    return 1 - (matthews_corrcoef(x, y) + 1) / 2
```

However, when I pass this function as the metric for the KNeighborsRegressor, I get the error

```
ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of continuous and binary targets
```

from the matthews_corrceof function. I added print statements in my mcc function to print x and y, and indeed x contains float numbers between 0 and 1, while y is a binary vector. I don't understand why my function is getting passed float values here, and how the jaccard metric (or any of the other built-in distance metrics for boolean vectors) deals with this.  Does anyone know what I can do?

I did try changing the algorithm to "brute", and it seems to have stopped the error but it takes too long to run to be a useful solution for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the brute force algorithm is the only way to faithfully use your custom metric.  Another possibility is to modify your metric to extend it to continuous values.

---

Ball Trees work by comparing distances to a smaller number of Ball centers, which won't be integer-valued like your data, and so your metric won't work.  See [this DS.SE post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/57343/55122) and [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49638947/10495893).

I think theoretically it could work with a kD-tree algorithm, but sklearn doesn't allow that either, for computational reasons.  See the note at the end of the parameters section of [the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KDTree.html#sklearn.neighbors.KDTree).  At time of posting, this reads

> Note: Callable functions in the metric parameter are NOT supported for KDTree
> and Ball Tree. Function call overhead will result in very poor performance.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know then how the metrics like jaccard, kulsinski, etc. work in sklearn? I can tell from the running time when I use those metrics that it is not using the brute force algorithm. Does it round the values to 0 or 1 to convert them back to binary?

Comment: Just checked the code on GitHub. It looks like they just take any non-zero values as True.